# Uber Ride API - Driver

Tags: uber-api

We are busy looking at Uber Ride API and would like to find out the following:

1. Is all_trips scope applicable if OAuth authorized user is an Uber driver?
2. Will Webhook invoke events everytime when a driver accepts/cancels/completes a trips?
3. will Webhook be invoked during a real trip while the app is under development or Only work in Sandbox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. No. The `all_trips` scope only works for riders.
2. Yes. Every trip status change triggers a webhook. Possible statuses changes are:

   - `processing`
   - `no_drivers_available`
   - `accepted`
   - `arriving`
   - `in_progress`
   - `driver_canceled`
   - `rider_canceled`
   - `completed`.

(List pulled from [here](https://developer.uber.com/docs/rides/api/v1-requests-current#section-request-statuses), according to the webhooks documentation [here](https://developer.uber.com/docs/rides/webhooks)).

3. Yes. If you grant your app the `all_trips` scope, the Uber API will send webhooks to the URL you have registered at developer.uber.com/dashboard for every trip you take, i.e. sandbox and real trips alike. Note that there is currently no way to flag an Uber app as "in development" or "in production".

Comment: Thanks for clarity.